# Como usar o evento onSnapFinish(); do jquery-panelsnap/

Tags: jquery, css, rolamento

estou com uma dúvida no plugin jquery-panelsnap (http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/) se trata de um plugin que trabalha com transição de sessões a partir do scroll.

Ele funciona muito bem, porém ao invés de usar todas as minhas sections com 100% de altura, como em algumas terei menos conteudo, gostaria que a mesma tivesse 50%  da minha tela, com isso ela iria atender o conteudo curto.

Porém ao fazer isso o plugin trava ao saltar para section subsequente, acredito que possa ser algum erro na compreensão do evento onSnapFinish e onSnapStart, abaixo está o exemplo com o erro que ocorre, alguém saberia a solução para esse bug > http://jsfiddle.net/korzzus/uspzc5qy/11/